# Windows Forms Settings Values Don't Persist Between Sessions

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, session, persistence

I am developing a Windows Forms application which ideally will store inventory values between sessions.

In the past, I have been able to save the Properties.Settings values between sessions. However, using similar code with my current application I am unable to do so.

Here is the snippet of code where I attempt to save my values:

```
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, double> ingredient in inventoryDictionary)
    {
        var ingredientUnit = unitList[ingredient.Key];
        lstInventory.Items.Add(item: string.Format(@"{0} {1} {2}", ingredient.Key, ingredient.Value, ingredientUnit));
        settings[ingredient.Key] = ingredient.Value;
        settings.Save();
    }
```

The values are stored during the active session, but once the form is closed the values always reset to default.

All of my settings are listed under the "User" scope, and have the "Type" of double as expected. Additionally, all the values in the settings are set to 0 by default.

Any assistance in this issue would be greatly appreciated. I've been able to save values between sessions before, I'm not sure why it isn't working at this point...

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with Properties.Settings.Default

Example:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.myColor = Color.AliceBlue;
```

If you want to persist it between sessions

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

See [The MSDN link here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397755(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thank you alainlompo, your method works as expected. Just as a reference, I defined settings as "Properties.Settings.Default" above. I was attempting to cast all settings values to a dictionary upon initial form load. However, this expression didn't work correctly as it returned '0' as all values.